# Laravel 7 - Login error (Users with roles)

Tags: php, laravel, forms, logging, roles

I am trying to create a new user with a specific role which is number 2. Everything seems to work fine, the user is created and the email is sent with their user data, the password is created randomly. But when I try to login with the created user it does not allow me, it seems that the user data is not valid. I'm thinking it's because of the save() function because when I use insert() there is no problem to login but I need the attach() function for role insert.

This is mi code:

- Function create

```
public function create()
    {
        $roles = Role::where('id', '<=', 6)
        ->orderby('id')->get();
        $external = Role::where('id', '=', 2)->get();
        $departments = Department::all(['id', 'department_name']);

        return view('user.create', compact('roles', 'departments','external'));   
    }
```

- Function to register and send email

```
     public function onlinePreRegistration(Request $request)
    {
        $correo = $request->get('email');
        $password = StudentsController::random_password();

        try {
          
       $user = User::create(['name'=>$email, "email"=>$email, "password"=>bcrypt($password)]);

       $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('id','2')->first());
            
        } catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {//manejo de errores
            $mensaje = "Ha ocurrido un error al crear el usuario externo. Consulte con el administrador el siguiente error:\n\n\n {$e->getMessage()}";
            return back()->withInput()->with('err', $mensaje);
        }

        $data = array('email'=>$email,'password'=>$password);
        Mail::send('external_registration_mail', $data, function($message) use ($email) {
            $message->to($email)->subject('Registro / Inscription / Registration');
            $message->from('email@gmail.com');
        });

        $mensaje = "Se hizo el envío por correo de las credencials de acceso al usuario externo: " . $email;

        return back()->with('success', $mensaje);
    }
```

- Form

```
            <form action="{{url('/send_email')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <div class="d-flex">
                <label class="col-4 text-right" for="">*Email: </label>
                <input class="form-control col-4" type="email" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="example@mail.com" maxlength="50" size="40">
                @foreach($external $ext)
                        <tr>
                            <td class="align-middle small text-center">{{$ext->display_name}}</td>
                            <td class="align-middle text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="{{$ext->id}}" id="checkIrRol" name="ext" {{$ext->pluck('id')->contains($ext->id) ? 'checked' : ''}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                <div class="col-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-success"><i class="material-icons" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;">send</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

- Function for random password

```
     public function random_password( $length = 8 ) {
            //$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()_-=+;:,.?"; //All chars
            $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%&*=+?";
            $password = substr( str_shuffle( $chars ), 0, $length );
            return $password;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, check if you allowed to [mass assign](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) fields `name`, `email` and `password`

---

```php
public function create()
    {
        $roles = Role::where('id', '<=', 6)->orderby('id')->get();
        //$external = Role::where('id', '=', 2)->get();
        // no need in second request as you already have role with id 2 in $roles
        $external = $roles->firstWhere('id', 2);
        // if id = 2 may change in future then
        // $roles = Role::where('id', '<=', 6)->orWhere('id', $notOnly2)->orderby('id')->get();
    }
```

---

function `random_password` can be replaced with `Str::random($length)` ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-str-random))

Comment: Yes, the mass assign for those fields is allowed

Comment: @ManyRodríguez what error message do you get and what in logs when your login attempt failed?

Comment: **Invalid email** but the message is general so it might not be the email but the password... I've also updated the onlinePreRegistration function on my Question but it still won't let me log in.

Comment: @ManyRodríguez hard to say. the only difference between `save` and `insert` that `insert` skips any model events. do you have any events or observers on `User` model?

Comment: No, I don't have any events or observers on the User model.